# Create a dictionary of cities and states in order to store a string in UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsarray, nsdictionary

I'm creating a UITableView with a list of States and once you select a state in one of the cells it will switch to the next view that will have a list of cities that correspond to that State. This is what I have so far with my array of cities:

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {

NSMutableArray *mainArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


        self.section1 = @[@"Alabama",@"Alaska",@"Arizona",@"Arkansas",@"California",@"Colorado",@"Connecticut",@"Delaware"];
        self.section2 = @[@"Florida",@"Georgia",@"Hawaii",@"Idaho",@"Illinois",@"Indiana",@"Iowa",@"Kansas",@"Kentucky",@"Louisiana"];
        self.section3 = @[@"Maine",@"Maryland",@"Massachusetts",@"Michigan",@"Minnesota",@"Mississippi",@"Misouri",@"Montana"];
        self.section4 = @[@"Nevada",@"Nebraska",@"New Hampshire",@"New Jersey",@"New Mexico",@"New York",@"North Carolina",@"North Dakota",@"Ohio",@"Ohio",@"Oklahoma",@"Oregon"];
        self.section5 = @[@"Pennsylvania",@"Rhode Island",@"South Carolina",@"South Dakota",@"Tennessee",@"Texas",@"Utah"];
        self.section6 = @[@"Vermont",@"Virginia",@"Washington",@"West Virginia",@"Wisconsin",@"Wyoming"];
    }
    return self;
}
```

So would I have to create a separate array of the cities, and then combine these two arrays into one dictionary, then sort the list accordingly? Also, I would like once the cell is selected to store and pass a string according to the city or state selected.

Like so: SanFrancisco.California

UPDATE:

Here are a bunch of arrays with all the cities that Craigslist offers service to broken down by state and city:

```
self.Alabama = @[@"auburn",
                          @"birmingham",
                          @"dothan",
                          @"florence / muscle shoals",
                          @"gadsden-anniston",
                          @"huntsville / decatur",
                          @"mobile",
                          @"montgomery",
                          @"tuscaloosa"];


        self.Alaska = @[@"anchorage / mat-su",
                        @"fairbanks",
                        @"kenai peninsula",
                        @"southeast alaska"];

        self.Arizona = @[@"flagstaff / sedona",
                         @"mohave county",
                         @"phoenix",
                         @"prescott",
                         @"show low",
                         @"sierra vista",
                         @"tucson",
                         @"yuma"];

        self.Arkansas = @[@"fayetteville",
                          @"fort smith",
                          @"jonesboro",
                          @"little rock",
                          @"texarkana"];

        self.California = @[@"bakersfield",
                            @"chico",
                            @"fresno / madera",
                            @"gold country",
                            @"hanford-corcoran",
                            @"humboldt county",
                            @"imperial county",
                            @"inland empire",
                            @"los angeles",
                            @"mendocino county",
                            @"merced",
                            @"modesto",
                            @"monterey bay",
                            @"orange county",
                            @"palm springs",
                            @"redding",
                            @"sacramento",
                            @"san diego",
                            @"san francisco bay area",
                            @"san luis obispo",
                            @"santa barbara",
                            @"santa maria",
                            @"siskiyou county",
                            @"stockton",
                            @"susanville",
                            @"ventura county",
                            @"visalia-tulare",
                            @"yuba-sutter"];

        self.Colorado = @[@"boulder",
                          @"colorado springs",
                          @"denver",
                          @"eastern CO",
                          @"fort collins / north CO",
                          @"high rockies",
                          @"pueblo",
                          @"western slope"];

        self.Connecticut = @[@"eastern CT",
                             @"hartford",
                             @"new haven",
                             @"northwest CT"];

        self.Delaware = @[@"delware"];

        self.Florida = @[@"daytona beach",
                         @"florida keys",
                         @"fort lauderdale",
                         @"ft myers / SW florida",
                         @"gainesville",
                         @"heartland florida",
                         @"jacksonville",
                         @"lakeland",
                         @"north central FL",
                         @"ocala",
                         @"okaloosa / walton",
                         @"orlando",
                         @"panama city",
                         @"pensacola",
                         @"sarasota-bradenton",
                         @"south florida",
                         @"space coast",
                         @"st augustine",
                         @"tallahassee",
                         @"tampa bay area",
                         @"treasure coast",
                         @"west palm beach"];

        self.Georgia = @[@"albany",
                         @"athens",
                         @"atlanta",
                         @"augusta",
                         @"brunswick",
                         @"columbus",
                         @"macon / warner robins",
                         @"northwest GA",
                         @"savannah / hinesville",
                         @"statesboro",
                         @"valdosta"];

        self.Hawaii = @[@"hawaii"];

        self.Idaho = @[@"boise",
                       @"east idaho",
                       @"lewiston / clarkston",
                       @"twin falls"];

        self.Illinois = @[@"bloomington-normal",
                          @"champaign urbana",
                          @"chicago",
                          @"decatur",
                          @"la salle co",
                          @"mattoon-charleston",
                          @"peoria",
                          @"rockford",
                          @"southern illinois",
                          @"springfield",
                          @"western IL"];

        self.Indiana = @[@"bloomington",
                         @"evansville",
                         @"fort wayne",
                         @"indianapolis",
                         @"kokomo",
                         @"lafayette / west lafayette",
                         @"muncie / anderson",
                         @"richmond",
                         @"south bend / michiana",
                         @"terre haute"];

        self.Iowa = @[@"ames",
                      @"cedar rapids",
                      @"des moines",
                      @"dubuque",
                      @"fort dodge",
                      @"iowa city",
                      @"mason city",
                      @"quad cities",
                      @"sioux city",
                      @"southeast IA",
                      @"waterloo / cedar falls"];

        self.Kansas = @[@"lawrence",
                        @"manhattan",
                        @"northwest KS",
                        @"salina",
                        @"southeast KS",
                        @"southwest KS",
                        @"topeka",
                        @"wichita"];

        self.Kentucky = @[@"bowling green",
                          @"eastern kentucky",
                          @"lexington",
                          @"louisville",
                          @"owensboro",
                          @"western KY"];

        self.Louisiana = @[@"baton rouge",
                           @"central louisiana",
                           @"houma",
                           @"lafayette",
                           @"lake charles",
                           @"monroe",
                           @"new orleans",
                           @"shreveport"];

        self.Maine = @[@"maine"];

        self.Maryland = @[@"annapolis",
                          @"baltimore",
                          @"eastern shore",
                          @"frederick",
                          @"southern maryland",
                          @"western maryland"];

        self.Massachusetts = @[@"boston",
                               @"cape cod / islands",
                               @"south coast",
                               @"western massachusetts",
                               @"worcester / central MA"];

        self.Michigan = @[@"ann arbor",
                          @"battle creek",
                          @"central michigan",
                          @"detroit metro",
                          @"flint",
                          @"grand rapids",
                          @"holland",
                          @"jackson",
                          @"kalamazoo",
                          @"lansing",
                          @"monroe",
                          @"muskegon",
                          @"northern michigan",
                          @"port huron",
                          @"saginaw-midland-baycity",
                          @"southwest michigan",
                          @"the thumb",
                          @"upper peninsula"];

        self.Mississippi = @[@"gulfport / biloxi",
                             @"hattiesburg",
                             @"jackson",
                             @"meridian",
                             @"north mississippi",
                             @"southwest MS"];

        self.Minnesota = @[@"bemidji",
                           @"brainerd",
                           @"duluth / superior",
                           @"mankato",
                           @"minneapolis / st paul",
                           @"rochester",
                           @"southwest MN",
                           @"st cloud"];

        self.Missouri = @[@"columbia / jeff city",
                          @"joplin",
                          @"kansas city",
                          @"kirksville",
                          @"lake of the ozarks",
                          @"southeast missouri",
                          @"springfield",
                          @"st joseph",
                          @"st louis"];

        self.Montana = @[@"billings",
                         @"bozeman",
                         @"butte",
                         @"great falls",
                         @"helena",
                         @"kalispell",
                         @"missoula",
                         @"eastern montana"];

        self.Nebraska = @[@"grand island",
                          @"lincoln",
                          @"north platte",
                          @"omaha / council bluffs",
                          @"scottsbluff / panhandle"];

        self.Nevada = @[@"elko",
                        @"las vegas",
                        @"reno / tahoe"];

        self.NewHampshire = @[@"New Hampshire"];

        self.NewJersey = @[@"central NJ",
                           @"jersey shore",
                           @"north jersey",
                           @"south jersey"];

        self.NewMexico = @[@"albuquerque",
                           @"clovis / portales",
                           @"farmington",
                           @"las cruces",
                           @"roswell / carlsbad",
                           @"santa fe / taos"];

        self.NewYork = @[@"albany",
                         @"binghamton",
                         @"buffalo",
                         @"catskills",
                         @"chautauqua",
                         @"elmira-corning",
                         @"finger lakes",
                         @"glens falls",
                         @"hudson valley",
                         @"ithaca",
                         @"long island",
                         @"new york city",
                         @"oneonta",
                         @"plattsburgh-adirondacks",
                         @"potsdam-canton-massena",
                         @"rochester",
                         @"syracuse",
                         @"twin tiers NY/PA",
                         @"utica-rome-oneida",
                         @"watertown"];

        self.NorthCarolina = @[@"asheville",
                               @"boone",
                               @"charlotte",
                               @"eastern NC",
                               @"fayetteville",
                               @"greensboro",
                               @"hickory / lenoir",
                               @"jacksonville",
                               @"outer banks",
                               @"raleigh / durham / CH",
                               @"wilmington",
                               @"winston-salem"];

        self.NorthDakota = @[@"bismarck",
                             @"fargo / moorhead",
                             @"grand forks",
                             @"north dakota"];

        self.Ohio = @[@"akron / canton",
                      @"ashtabula",
                      @"athens",
                      @"chillicothe",
                      @"cincinnati",
                      @"cleveland",
                      @"columbus",
                      @"dayton / springfield",
                      @"lima / findlay",
                      @"mansfield",
                      @"sandusky",
                      @"toledo",
                      @"tuscarawas co",
                      @"youngstown",
                      @"zanesville / cambridge"];

        self.Oklahoma = @[@"lawton",
                          @"northwest OK",
                          @"oklahoma city",
                          @"stillwater",
                          @"tulsa"];

        self.Oregon = @[@"bend",
                        @"corvallis/albany",
                        @"east oregon",
                        @"eugene",
                        @"klamath falls",
                        @"medford-ashland",
                        @"oregon coast",
                        @"portland",
                        @"roseburg",
                        @"salem"];

        self.Pennsylvania = @[@"altoona-johnstown",
                              @"cumberland valley",
                              @"erie",
                              @"harrisburg",
                              @"lancaster",
                              @"lehigh valley",
                              @"meadville",
                              @"philadelphia",
                              @"pittsburgh",
                              @"poconos",
                              @"reading",
                              @"scranton / wilkes-barre",
                              @"state college",
                              @"williamsport",
                              @"york"];

        self.RhodeIsland = @[@"Rhode Island"];

        self.SouthCarolina = @[@"charleston",
                               @"columbia",
                               @"florence",
                               @"greenville / upstate",
                               @"hilton head",
                               @"myrtle beach"];

        self.SouthDakota = @[@"northeast SD",
                             @"pierre / central SD",
                             @"rapid city / west SD",
                             @"sioux falls / SE SD",
                             @"south dakota"];

        self.Tennessee = @[@"chattanooga",
                           @"clarksville",
                           @"cookeville",
                           @"jackson",
                           @"knoxville",
                           @"memphis",
                           @"nashville",
                           @"tri-cities"];

        self.Texas = @[@"abilene",
                       @"amarillo",
                       @"austin",
                       @"beaumont / port arthur",
                       @"brownsville",
                       @"college station",
                       @"corpus christi",
                       @"dallas / fort worth",
                       @"deep east texas",
                       @"del rio / eagle pass",
                       @"el paso",
                       @"galveston",
                       @"houston",
                       @"killeen / temple / ft hood",
                       @"laredo",
                       @"lubbock",
                       @"mcallen / edinburg",
                       @"odessa / midland",
                       @"san angelo",
                       @"san antonio",
                       @"san marcos",
                       @"southwest TX",
                       @"texoma",
                       @"tyler / east TX",
                       @"victoria",
                       @"waco",
                       @"wichita falls"];

        self.Utah = @[@"logan",
                      @"ogden-clearfield",
                      @"provo / orem",
                      @"salt lake city",
                      @"st george"];

        self.Vermont = @[@"Vermont"];

        self.Virginia = @[@"charlottesville",
                          @"danville",
                          @"fredericksburg",
                          @"hampton roads",
                          @"harrisonburg",
                          @"lynchburg",
                          @"new river valley",
                          @"richmond",
                          @"roanoke",
                          @"southwest VA",
                          @"winchester"];

        self.Washington = @[@"bellingham",
                            @"kennewick-pasco-richland",
                            @"moses lake",
                            @"olympic peninsula",
                            @"pullman / moscow",
                            @"seattle-tacoma",
                            @"skagit / island / SJI",
                            @"spokane / coeur d'alene",
                            @"wenatchee",
                            @"yakima"];

        self.WestVirginia = @[@"charleston",
                              @"eastern panhandle",
                              @"huntington-ashland",
                              @"morgantown",
                              @"northern panhandle",
                              @"parkersburg-marietta",
                              @"southern WV",
                              @"west virginia (old)"];

        self.Wisconsin = @[@"appleton-oshkosh-FDL",
                           @"eau claire",
                           @"green bay",
                           @"janesville",
                           @"kenosha-racine",
                           @"la crosse",
                           @"madison",
                           @"milwaukee",
                           @"northern WI",
                           @"sheboygan",
                           @"wausau"];

        self.Wyoming = @[@"Wyoming"];

NSMutableDictionary *dic1=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
        [dic1 setValue:@"Alabama" forKey:@"state"];
        [dic1 setValue:self.Alabama forKey:@"cities"];


        NSMutableDictionary *dic2=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
        [dic2 setValue:@"Alaska" forKey:@"state"];
        [dic2 setValue:self.Alaska forKey:@"cities"];

        NSMutableDictionary *dic3=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
        [dic3 setValue:@"Arizona" forKey:@"states"];
        [dic3 setValue:self.Arizona forKey:@"cities"];


        NSMutableDictionary *dic4=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
        [dic4 setValue:@"Arkansas" forKey:@"states"];
        [dic4 setValue:self.Arkansas forKey:@"cities"];

        NSMutableDictionary *dic5=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
        [dic5 setValue:@"California" forKey:@"states"];
        [dic5 setValue:self.California forKey:@"cities"];


        NSMutableDictionary *dic6=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
        [dic6 setValue:@"Colorado" forKey:@"states"];
        [dic6 setValue:self.Colorado forKey:@"cities"];

        NSMutableDictionary *dic7=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
        [dic7 setValue:@"Connecticut" forKey:@"state"];
        [dic7 setValue:self.Connecticut forKey:@"cities"];


        NSMutableDictionary *dic8=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
        [dic8 setValue:@"Delaware" forKey:@"state"];
        [dic8 setValue:self.Delaware forKey:@"cities"];

        NSMutableDictionary *dic9=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
        [dic9 setValue:@"Florida" forKey:@"states"];
        [dic9 setValue:self.Florida forKey:@"cities"];


        NSMutableDictionary *dic10=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
        [dic10 setValue:@"Georgia" forKey:@"states"];
        [dic10 setValue:self.Georgia forKey:@"cities"];

        NSMutableDictionary *dic11=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
        [dic11 setValue:@"Hawaii" forKey:@"states"];
        [dic11 setValue:self.Hawaii forKey:@"cities"];


        NSMutableDictionary *dic12=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
        [dic12 setValue:@"Idaho" forKey:@"states"];
        [dic12 setValue:self.Idaho forKey:@"cities"];

        NSMutableDictionary *dic13=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
        [dic13 setValue:@"Illinois" forKey:@"state"];
        [dic13 setValue:self.Illinois forKey:@"cities"];


        NSMutableDictionary *dic14=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
        [dic14 setValue:@"Indiana" forKey:@"state"];
        [dic14 setValue:self.Indiana forKey:@"cities"];

        NSMutableDictionary *dic15=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
        [dic15 setValue:@"Iowa" forKey:@"states"];
        [dic15 setValue:self.Iowa forKey:@"cities"];


        NSMutableDictionary *dic16=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
        [dic16 setValue:@"Kansas" forKey:@"states"];
        [dic16 setValue:self.Kansas forKey:@"cities"];

        NSMutableDictionary *dic17=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
        [dic17 setValue:@"Kentucky" forKey:@"states"];
        [dic17 setValue:self.Kentucky forKey:@"cities"];


        NSMutableDictionary *dic18=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
        [dic18 setValue:@"Louisiana" forKey:@"states"];
        [dic18 setValue:self.Louisiana forKey:@"cities"];

        NSMutableDictionary *dic19=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
        [dic19 setValue:@"Maine" forKey:@"state"];
        [dic19 setValue:self.Maine forKey:@"cities"];


        NSMutableDictionary *dic20=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
        [dic20 setValue:@"Maryland" forKey:@"state"];
        [dic20 setValue:self.Maryland forKey:@"cities"];

        NSMutableDictionary *dic21=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
        [dic21 setValue:@"Massachusetts" forKey:@"states"];
        [dic21 setValue:self.Massachusetts forKey:@"cities"];


        NSMutableDictionary *dic22=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
        [dic22 setValue:@"Michigan" forKey:@"states"];
        [dic22 setValue:self.Michigan forKey:@"cities"];

        NSMutableDictionary *dic23=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
        [dic23 setValue:@"Minnesota" forKey:@"states"];
        [dic23 setValue:self.Minnesota forKey:@"cities"];


        NSMutableDictionary *dic24=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
        [dic24 setValue:@"Mississippi" forKey:@"states"];
        [dic24 setValue:self.Mississippi forKey:@"cities"];

        NSMutableDictionary *dic25=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
        [dic25 setValue:@"Missouri" forKey:@"states"];
        [dic25 setValue:self.Missouri forKey:@"cities"];


        NSMutableDictionary *dic26=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
        [dic26 setValue:@"Montana" forKey:@"states"];
        [dic26 setValue:self.Montana forKey:@"cities"];

        NSMutableDictionary *dic27=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
        [dic27 setValue:@"Nebraska" forKey:@"states"];
        [dic27 setValue:self.Nebraska forKey:@"cities"];


        NSMutableDictionary *dic28=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
        [dic28 setValue:@"Nevada" forKey:@"states"];
        [dic28 setValue:self.Nevada forKey:@"cities"];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest having a class for each State, in which you have properties such as a NSString for the State and an Array that contains all the corresponding cities. Then, store the State Objects in a Dictionary with the State names as keys.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking the same thing too. Holy crap, this is going to take forever. I'll post it when I'm done so that no else has to do this tedious work.

Comment: Free feel to post back what you have, would be more than glad to assist further, should it be needed. Have a good day.